How does the credit system work in pam_pwquality?
Something has been really bugging me in he manual for the pam module pwquality (see man pwquality.conf).
I quote:
       minlen
           Minimum acceptable size for the new password (plus one if  credits  are  not  disabled  which  is  the
           default). (See pam_pwquality(8).)  Cannot be set to lower value than 6. (default 8)

       dcredit
           The  maximum  credit for having digits in the new password. If less than 0 it is the minimum number of
           digits in the new password. (default 0)

       ucredit
           The maximum credit for having uppercase characters in the new password.  If less  than  0  it  is  the
           minimum number of uppercase characters in the new password. (default 0)

       lcredit
           The  maximum  credit  for  having  lowercase characters in the new password.  If less than 0 it is the
           minimum number of lowercase characters in the new password. (default 0)

The minlen sections says it adds plus one by default. Why? I don't understand how the credit system works and why +1 would need to be added int the calculation.
I'm also not sure how the negative values for dcredit ucredit and lcredit are interpreted.
It's all very confusing to me.. if anyone could explain with an example it would greatly help me!

The goal here is to encourage users to pick strong passwords.
The best test for password strength is the raw length of the password, so minlen sets the minimum length.
However, character set is also a factor.  So a password with all lowercase letters is weaker than one with mixed case which is weaker than one with mixed case and numbers, etc...
So, for instance, minlen could be set to something high like 12 with ucredit=1 and lcredit=1, so we can give credit for each character picked from a different set of characters.  An all lowercase password (or all uppercase) would have a credit of 1 and a minimum length of 12+1-1.
If ucredit=2 then a password that was mixed uppercase and lowercase could get up to 2 credits for uppercase letters, allowing it to be as short as 10 characters.
If instead ucredit=-2 then it would be rejected if it didn't have at least 2 uppercase characters no matter how long it was, but would not be allowed to be shorter than the minimum 12.
So if all four of the ?credit settings were set to 1 with minlen=12 then the minimum password length would be 9 if you used at least one character from each set.
If you set minlen=16 and all of ?credit=2 then the minimum length would again be 9 but 15 would be required for an all lowercase password.
